# What's the proper term for the URL sans query param?

Tags: url, terminology

Say you have the following URL:

http://example.com/path?param=value

"param=value" is the query string
"/path" is path
"http://" is the protocol

What's the proper name for "http://example.com/path" only?

thanks!
-nikita

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Generic Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax) of an URI Scheme on Wikipedia:

> [...] Every URI is defined as consisting of four parts, as follows:
>
> ```
> <scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]
> ```

So "http://domain.com/path" is made of the `<scheme name>` and `<hierarchical part>` parts, there is no name to designate this couple as a whole.

The Uniform Resource Locator page on Wikipedia and it's [Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax) is another interesting resource.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a name for that particular cluster of parts, which are `Scheme`, `Authority`, `Path` respectively. You're just leaving off the `Query` and `Fragment` bits.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:**    Just call it an absolute URL or simply URL.

---

**In detail:**    There are many terms for that depending on the context.

According to the URL terminology (RFC 1808), your example is:

- a *URL*:

  ```
  URL         = ( absoluteURL | relativeURL ) [ "#" fragment ]
  ```
- an *absoluteURL*:

  ```
  absoluteURL = generic-RL | ( scheme ":" *( uchar | reserved ) )
  ```
- a *generic-RL*:

  ```
  generic-RL  = scheme ":" relativeURL
  ```

And according to the URI terminology (RFC 3986), your example is:

- a *URI*:

  ```
  URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
  ```
- a *URI-reference*:

  ```
  URI-reference = URI / relative-ref
  ```

  and
- an *absolute-URI*:

  ```
  absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]
  ```

So just call it absolute URL/URI or URL/URI in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's still just a URL. The items after '?' just facilitate the passing of parameters through an HTTP GET request.

Here's a good dissection of the parts of a URL: [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/)

Comment: True as far as it goes, except that the same URI syntax applies to schemes other than HTTP.