# Terms for URL with Query Parameters

Tags: url, web, terminology

Say I have a website that accepts URLs of the form:

```
http://mywebsite.com/viewdata?content=aggregated&format=circular
```

Where the content is modified by a parameter (`content`) and the format is modified by a parameter (`format`).

What is the term for this sort of URL? How do you refer to the URLs of a "dynamic" website? Is there a difference in terms for parameters that change the content vs the presentation?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506964/whats-the-proper-term-for-the-url-sans-query-param), but I'm trying to figure out what to call the entire URL and the process of using the URL to dynamically change page content.

Sorry if the question is a bit unclear: it's hard to ask when you don't even know what words to use.

Comment: The best terms that I could come up with are "Stateful URL" or "Bookmarkable URL". Neither of which are very good, and neither of which are standard as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

you got to learn this tutorial

http://w3schools.com/php/ or http://w3schools.com/asp programming or .... langs

Comment: How do these help me? In any case, the question is language agnostic.

Comment: url formation is like this url/REQUEST_URI?QUERY_STRING. REQUEST_URI represents a path to an executable file on your server or an resource file like html,js file or an image

Comment: Ok, but that's not the question. The question is asking for the terms used in the area of dynamic URLs. I don't see how a link to two programming languages helps here.